# User-Agent doesn't change in HTA application with IE=EDGE content (Javascript, setRequestHeader)

Tags: javascript

When adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />` into HTA application, `http.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0..");` does not work.

No problem when setting it as `content="IE=9"` and below.
Any ideas?

Comment: HTAs are not supported in IE>9, that might have something to do with the problem. Please define "_does not work_".

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Answer (score 0):

Using `http = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead of `http = new XMLHttpRequest()` fixes this problem!